# Firebug - turn of (deactivate) panels that are not used

Tags: firefox, performance, firebug

I have all firebux panels on right now. There is one javascript application that horibly laggs when all panels are active.
So how do I turn panel (HTML, DOM, CSS, Net) off when I don't need one, but I need others (Cookies, Console)?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn only some panels (Console, Cookies, Net) off, and not others. To do this, just click on the arrow on the right side of the panel title and deactivate it from the contextual menu.